# How to get rid of this Mercurial warning? (hostsecurity/hostfingerprints)

Tags: mercurial

Since I moved to Ubuntu 18.04 with Mercurial 4.5.3, I am seeing the following warning:

`(SHA-1 fingerprint for bitbucket.org found in legacy [hostfingerprints] section; if you trust this fingerprint, remove the old SHA-1 fingerprint from [hostfingerprints] and add the following entry to the new [hostsecurity] section: bitbucket.org:fingerprints=sha256:32:12:90:9a:70:64:82:1c:5b:52:cc:c3:0a:d0:79:db:e1:a8:62:1b:9a:9a:4c:f4:72:40:1c:a7:3a:d3:0a:8c)`

Now I understand and appreciate the warning. However, I'd like to silence it. Preferably by adding the respective section and entry in `.hgrc`:

```
[hostsecurity]
bitbucket.org:fingerprints=sha256:32:12:90:9a:70:64:82:1c:5b:52:cc:c3:0a:d0:79:db:e1:a8:62:1b:9a:9a:4c:f4:72:40:1c:a7:3a:d3:0a:8c
```

But regardless whether I put the new `[hostsecurity]` section before the old `[hostfingerprints]` section or not, the warning continues to show. So I am looking for a way to silence it, preferably just for that hostname and inside `.hgrc`.

Unlike some happy people who can always work exclusively with the latest distro versions, I still have some pretty old distro versions running and Mercurial on them. So the old entry is required especially on those older Mercurial versions.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like a bug in how mercurial is parsing the config file. I'd report this as such on mercurial's bugzilla. Thankfully 18.04 is new enough that you actually have a pretty recent version of mercurial so it's probably still there in the development version unless someone has noticed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

First remove (comment out) the `hostfingerprints` section:

```
# [hostfingerprints]
# bitbucket.org = ..:..:...
```

Then add the new hostsecurity section:

```
hostsecurity]
bitbucket.org = sha256:..:..:... (with whatever the error message suggests)
```

It appears that you can't use the `bitbucket.org:fingerprints=...` stanza as the warning suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took answering my question, but unless I am badly mistaken you didn't actually read my full question. I don't have the luxury of using the latest and greatest Mercurial version and so I need both of these sections while being able to silence the warning. That's what my question is about.